# How to make multiple language website with including appropriate files on PHP?

Tags: php, lang

I have 2 languages in my website. I want to include appropriate **file** according to selected language. For example, `<a href='index.php?lang=en'>English</a>` and `<a href='index.php?lang=tr'>Turkish</a>`. If user clicks over first hyperlink (English) I want to display this information (with HTML tags):

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
How are you
```

Otherwise:

```
<h1>Selam</h1>
Nasılsın
```

I also dont want user selected language to change if user go to other page inside website.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which serverside technology are you using?

Comment: @EmilAzizov You might be interested in following the proposals for potential new SE sites including [Turkish Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30873/turkish-language-usage?referrer=wKPqNxBBY-xKcrw-ScJbLA2) and [StackOverflow in Turkish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish?referrer=6DTBHmak2NY7uyvjVsZajA2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use .ini files to hold the translated versions of you text for example, en.ini will contain:

```
hello    = "Hello"
greeting = "How are you"
```

While tr.ini will contain:

```
hello    = "Selam"
greeting = "Nasılsın"
```

Both are simple text files (saved in UTF-8 format).
Now you can see that the strings have common names in all languages (hello & greeting) which cab be used in the code like this:

```
// First, load the appropriate language file:

$lang = "en";
$strings = parse_ini_file( "$lang.ini" );

// Now we can use the following code no matter what $lang indicates (tr or en):

echo( "<h1>{$strings[ "hello" ]}</h1><br/>{$strings[ "greeting" ]}" );
```

One thing you should be concious of:

- Since `parse_ini_file` reads a file from the file system, you must validate the value in $lang very carefully! don't rely on user input in any way for the value of `$lang` as it might be malicious (link to `page.php?lang=en` is not good enough).
  Check the value of $lang against your own white list for example: `$langs = array( "en", "tr" );` and if that fails, redirect to a general error page or something...

Answer (score 4):

The best solution for you is named Gettext

See :
[PHP manual Gettext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)
[Localizing PHP web sites using gettext](http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/)

This is, without any discussion, the best way to have a multi language web site. Gettext is faster than any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to map all your words in the database , detect which language is , after that retrieve all the data from the database by mapping the language ID (EN for English and TU for Turkish) and the specified word..You can use "If , else" for the same approach ...